# Intel i5 2520m vulnerability

Tags: security, intel-core-i5

I am using a computer with i5 2520m processor and I am cocerned about the latest CPU vulnerabilities like TAA, MDSUM, MLPDS, MFBDS, MSBDS, V3a, V4.

The processor itself was discontinued by Intel.

As stated by Intel the risk or chance to exploit „classical“ spectre/meltdown is very low.

How does it look with this newer vulnerabilities? 
How to find out if my CPU is affected? There is no information from Intel and for me buying a new PC makes no sense because modern i5 offer only slightly better performance and disposing of my current PC and buying a new one will contribute to the environmental pollution.

Comment: Any exploit of any significance will indicate what architectures are vulnerable to it.  What products are indicated in the white papers for the vulnerabilities in question?

Comment: How old?   I have an X230 i5 3230 dating from 2013 and it got a BIOS update in 2019.  If the vulnerability is low as you report and the computer is satisfactory at this point, keep using. All computers die at some point and must be disposed of in an environmentally responsible manner